# iphone simulator crashes when it tries to access user location

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-location

for some reason my code causes my program to crash. does anyone know why or how to fix it?

```
NSLog(@"here");
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location]; 
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations]; 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate = [location coordinate];
 NSLog(@" this is %@", workingCoordinate.latitude);
```

it makes it to the first NSLog, but somewhere between the first and second it crashes. My guess is that it has to do with the CLLocation *location line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct containing two non-object fields of type `CLLocationDegrees`.   The `%@` passed to the `NSLog` will try to interpret the value as an object reference and that is causing the crash.

Try:
    NSLog(@" this is %d", workingCoordinate.latitude);

Comment: That allowed the program to work, but it gave a latitude that is impossible: 14212. On my map though it is adding the coordinates of this annotation to Lat 0 long 0

Comment: That's because latitude and longitude are double, so you can't use %d, you would use %f format specifier.  Check the [CLLocationDegrees definition in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)